# D3.js selecting a part of data to be visualized from a large dataset

Tags: d3.js, bigdata

I have a large real time incoming data for visualization. I have the speed and time in the dataset. Like if you consider CSV format its like the following

```
Speed, Time
s1,    t1
.......
sn,tn
```

But I want to visualize say only speed for t1-t10. How can I do that? To the broader sense i should able to select how many time frames i will keep in the chart. May be from t1-t10, t5-t10 or t10-t25 etc.

Have anyone worked with problem like this?

Comment: Well, you would need to filter your data accordingly, for example with the [`.filter()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `.filter` method is usually the easiest way of solving a reduction of data for later processing or visualization, in your particular example I would prefer other strategy:

1. Sort the array with [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) `data.sort(function(a, b){return a.Time > b.Time;}))`
2. Create a [bisector](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_bisector) `var bisect = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.Time; });`
3. We need bisector `left` and `right`, so:

   `var biLeft = bisec.left, biRight = bisec.right;`
4. With these functions now we can slice the array and extract the requested information:

   var subset = data.slice(biLeft(data, "t5"), biRight(data, "t10"));

Answer (score 0):

I have found a good way to solve the issue.
At the beginning I may slice the full data using the following code:

```
var data=data.slice(startIndex,endIndex);
```

In this way by changing the starting and ending parameter I can easily change the plots